# Database Details in PDF are not getting filled?

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am extracting data from MySQL database using php and exporting it as PDF. The columns are not getting filled due to the PDF page size. How do I push the unfilled columns to next line? So that first line has 4 columns and next line has another 4 columns, so on..

```
<?php

//include connection file
include_once "connection.php";
include_once 'fpdf/fpdf.php';

class PDF extends FPDF {
    // Page header
    function Header() {
    }

    // Page footer
    function Footer() {
        // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C');
    }
}

$db = new dbObj();
$connString = $db->getConnstring();
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = $connString->prepare("SELECT ID, Name, Wrongs, Rights, Percentage, Age FROM Datas WHERE ID=?");
$query->bind_param('s', $id);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->get_result();
$display_heading = array('ID' => 'ID', 'Name' => 'Name', 'Wrongs' => 'Wrongs', 'Rights' => 'Rights', 'Percentage' => 'Percentage', 'Age' => 'Age');

//$result = mysqli_query($connString, "SELECT ID, Name, Wrongs, Rights, Percentage, Age FROM Datas") or die("database error:". mysqli_error($connString));
$header = mysqli_query($connString, "SHOW columns FROM Datas");

$pdf = new PDF();
//header
$pdf->AddPage();
//foter page
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
foreach ($header as $heading) {
    $pdf->Cell(45, 12, $display_heading[$heading['Field']], 1);
}
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $pdf->Ln();
    foreach ($row as $column) {
        $pdf->Cell(45, 12, $column, 1);
    }
}
$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: If PDF output is wide, then fpdf providers settings 
- to change orientation (P / L )
- to change page size (A3 / A4 / A5/ ...)

will these changes suit you?

Please refer a link 
http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/addpage.htm

Comment: Maybe in the script for ```foreach ($header as $heading)``` can be changed to support 4 column entries per line?

Comment: Unfortunately the page size should stay A4.